# man <command> doesn't display anything after package installation with conda on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, manpage, anaconda, conda, pager

When I try to get the manpages with `man` it seems to display nothing and behaves as though I just pressed enter

```
~$ man ls
~$ man man
```

I have tried solutions from these pages to no avail
[question1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356689/ubuntu-man-command-display-blank-pages) [question2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960969/man-command-not-working). This last [question](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162668) matches my condition exactly but the fixes doesn't seem to work. Although `info` seems to work.

Here are some additional information:

```
~$ man --version
man 2.7.6.1

~$ type -p man
/usr/bin/man

~$ type -t man
file

~$ manpath
/home/abhilash/anaconda3/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man

~$ uname -a
Linux abhilash-ThinkPad-T440 4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPDATE**

```
~$ type -a man
man is /usr/bin/man

~$ env | grep 'PAGER\|^MAN'
~$
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
~$ ls -1 /usr/share/man/man1 | wc -l
2145

~$ ls -l "$(type -p pager)"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abhilash abhilash 18 Apr 16 18:43 /home/abhilash/anaconda3/bin/pager -> ../lib/R/bin/pager

~$ ls -l "$(readlink "$(type -p pager)")"
ls: cannot access '../lib/R/bin/pager': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Show also: `type -a man` and `env | grep 'PAGER\|^MAN'`

Comment: I've added them as an update

Comment: Do you have any files in `/usr/share/man/man1/`?

Comment: How about `ls -l "$(type -p pager)"` and (assuming it is a symlink): `ls -l "$(readlink "$(type -p pager)")"`

Comment: @terdon : I have 2145 files in that folder.

Comment: @glennjackman The second command seems to say there is no such file. Is that expected ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out, after the anaconda installation or some package installation through conda, the default pager is re-written. The exact cause of this is unknown. 
Just some more information

```
~$ anaconda --version
anaconda Command line client (version 1.6.9)
~$ conda --version 
conda 4.4.10
~$ history | grep conda
  108  bash Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh 
  110  anaconda-navigator
  181  anaconda-navigator
  187  anaconda-navigator
  311  conda info --envs
  312  conda install rpy2
  313  conda search PySide
  314  conda search Python
  366  conda install findspark
  367  conda info --envs
  370  conda install findspark
  373  conda search findspark
  374  conda install -c conda-forge findspark 
  495  anaconda --version
  496  conda --version 
  497  conda list
  499  history | grep conda
```

My strongest guess is that rpy2 installation had this effect of changing the pager information given the time of events.

But these are the steps I took to solve the issue.

```
~$ update-alternatives --display pager
pager - auto mode
  link best version is /bin/less
  link currently points to /bin/less
  link pager is /usr/bin/pager
  slave pager.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/pager.1.gz
/bin/less - priority 77
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz
/bin/more - priority 50
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz

~$ rm /home/abhilash/anaconda3/bin/pager
```

Ensure that the pager defaults to the one that came with man-db by typing the following to confirm

```
~$ ls -l "$(type -p pager)"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Apr  9 13:57 /usr/bin/pager -> /etc/alternatives/pager
```

This solution was arrived at after going through this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623992/what-is-the-default-pager-used-by-man-pages) in an attempt to set the pager to default.

Thanks to [glenn](https://askubuntu.com/users/10127/glenn-jackman) and [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) for their inputs in solving this issue.

Comment: +1 for both your Q and A. Don't forget to click the check mark next to your answer in 40 hours or so when it let's you.

Comment: Just the `rm /home/abhilash/anaconda3/bin/pager` would have probably done it.

Comment: For this  this was caused by Microsoft R Open.... `which pager` showed that I wasn't using `/usr/bin/pager`. Just had to correct my $PATH order and it was fixed.

Comment: @WillZ is this more of an Anaconda problem or an R problem?

Comment: @AaronHall I can't remember exactly, as far as I can recall for me it happened after I installed MRO.

Comment: Wow, never could have guessed it without this comment. Thanks a lot, Abhilash.