# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my MSI laptop, man command does not work anymore

Tags: manpage

The installation had no problem and man was working fine till yesterday. However, today the man command does not work anymore. 
Please help troubleshoot.

Thanks
mas192

Comment: "does not work"  does not mean anything and is not enough to ask for troubleshooting. What command did you execute? What error did you get? What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem, 
[man <command> doesn't display anything after package installation with conda on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026441/man-command-doesnt-display-anything-after-package-installation-with-conda-on)

something in my anaconda installation affected my man pages. And this solution above has fixed it.

Thanks, Abilash(https://askubuntu.com/users/820071/abhilash)